# GitHub Action to push commits to AWS CodeCommit: Host key verification failed

Tags: git, github, ssh, github-actions, aws-codecommit

I'm trying to create a GitHub Action that pushes any commits to an AWS CodeCommit repo. For this, I'm using a workflow with a single `main.yml` file using the [composite run steps action](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-composite-run-steps-action) method for creating a GitHub Action. This is what the Action looks like:

```yaml
name: CI
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
jobs:
  codecommit:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: pushes to codecommit
        env:
          CODECOMMIT_URL: ${{ secrets.CODECOMMIT_URL }}
          HOST_KEY: ${{ secrets.HOST_KEY }}
          SSH_CONFIG: ${{ secrets.SSH_CONFIG }}
          SSH_PRIVATE_KEY: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
        shell: bash
        run: |
          mkdir .ssh && cd .ssh && echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > id_rsa && chmod 600 id_rsa
          echo "$SSH_CONFIG" > config && chmod 600 config
          echo "$HOST_KEY" > known_hosts && chmod 600 known_hosts && cd ..
          git remote add codecommit "$CODECOMMIT_URL"
          git push codecommit master --force
```

Breaking this down:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
```

Whenever changes are pushed to the master branch...

```yaml
jobs:
  codecommit:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
```

Run a single job called `codecommit` that first checks out the code in the repo and makes it available in the runner's file system.

```yaml
      - name: push to codecommit
        env:
          CODECOMMIT_URL: ${{ secrets.CODECOMMIT_URL }}
          HOST_KEY: ${{ secrets.HOST_KEY }}
          SSH_CONFIG: ${{ secrets.SSH_CONFIG }}
          SSH_PRIVATE_KEY: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
        shell: bash
```

Run a single step called `push to codecommit` with some environment variables, `CODECOMMIT_URL`, `HOST_KEY`, `SSH_CONFIG`, and `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY`. These are:

`CODECOMMIT_URL`: the ssh url for the CodeCommit repo.

`HOST_KEY`: the result of running `ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com` to get the host key for the GitHub repo.

`SSH_CONFIG`: This is the git config to be used for git:

```
Host git-codecommit.*.amazonaws.com
  User {SSH Username here}
  IdentityFile .ssh/id_rsa
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

`SSH_PRIVATE_KEY`: the private key that goes inside `id_rsa`.

```yaml
        run: |
          mkdir .ssh && cd .ssh && echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > id_rsa && chmod 600 id_rsa
```

Run a series of commands, and start by making a directory called `.ssh`, entering this directory, and creating a file `id_rsa` that is accessible by the system. This file contains the private SSH key.

```yaml
echo "$SSH_CONFIG" > config && chmod 600 config
```

Save the SSH config to a file called `config` and give the system access rights to this file.

```yaml
echo "$HOST_KEY" > known_hosts && chmod 600 known_hosts && cd ..
```

Save the host key into a file called `known_hosts`, give the system access rights to this file, and then navigate back to the root directory for the repo.

```yaml
git remote add codecommit "$CODECOMMIT_URL"
git push codecommit master --force
```

Add the CodeCommit URL as a remote for git, and attempt to push to this remote.

It looks like CodeCommit is still not recognizing GitHub as verified. I get this response from running this Action:

```sh
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Am I missing something in this configuration?

Comment: I have a similar use case that needs to do this, were you able to find a solution?

Comment: Your path to ID file might be wrong as you are already in the .ssh directory?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be doing:

```
$ ssh-keyscan -H git-codecommit.<region>.amazonaws.com
```

... and then adding the result to:

```
~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your question, it helped a lot.

I had a Permission denied experience that I could not resolve. So basically I tried to run a docker and test it.
And in my experience, I had to use Note 4 from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-ssh-unixes.html.

So I replaced

```
git clone ssh://git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/MyDemoRepo my-demo-repo
```

by

```
git clone ssh://Your-SSH-Key-ID@git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/MyDemoRepo my-demo-repo
```